# Что выбрать из java-фреймворков для вывода коллекции: Spring MVC, Struts, Mojarra(JSF)

Tags: framework, java

Доброго дня, уважаемые Java-гуру. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой фреймворк лучше выбрать для быстрой реализации простого учебного примера. Предварительно отобрал следующие
Spring MVC, Struts, Mojarra(JSF).
Причина выбора этих- пишу в Netbeans и там эту фреймворки уже интегрированы в IDE. К сожалению у меня нет нескольких десятков лет на изучение всех возможных фреймворках и нужно написать небольшое приложение. Быстродействие самого приложения не критично.
Хочу реализовать задачу вывода на сайт коллекций с возможностью редактирования элементов

Comment: Берите Spring MVC, он более востребован.

Answer (score 1):

[вот тут](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/top-4-java-web-frameworks-revealed-real-life-usage-data-of-spring-mvc-vaadin-gwt-and-jsf/) показано что спрниг самый популярный. Я сам задавался этим вопросом где-то в августе - что учить, какой фреймворк. Один "профессор" посоветовал мне Струтс2. Оказалось что это труп почти. Хорошо что я погуглил предварительно...

Answer (score 1):

Spring, по сути сейчас стандарт в мире Enterprise разработки. Учите его, особенно если хотите в дальнейшем найти работу в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0):

Для быстрой разработки простого приложения подойдет [Spark](http://sparkjava.com/) + шаблонизатор [Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/)
Плюсы: можно сразу начинать писать без изучения гайдов.
Минусы: для более сложных приложений не подойдут